# Migration to Stack Overflow locked but not actually migrated

Tags: bug, specific-question, migration

There's something wrong with the migration of [Seperating GLX from X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323524/seperating-glx-from-x11) to had 4 votes to migrate to Stack Overflow. It looks like the migration is in limbo: it's started (the question has been locked), but the question hasn't appeared on Stack Overflow (the asker has since then [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625663/separating-x11-and-glx) it). It's been weeks, so this is not due to caching.